# Android App won't launch after adding background images

Tags: android, layout, launch, android-image

After adding two background images to my app it will no longer launch in the emulator. It gets to the uploading portion and just sits there, I've left it for 30 minutes for what is usually a 30 second upload and start. The background images are added to the main visible layout pages.

The images are approximately 600k and 900k each. I copied them into all 4 of the drawables folders.

Anyone know what I did wrong or how to fix it? There are no errors reported.

Answer (score 0):

For starters you dont need to put them in all four folders. Just place one into the drawable HD folder